# java.net.UnknownHostException: 189.216.xxx.xxx:58157: invalid IPv6 address - when accessing h2-console in SpringBoot App

Tags: h2

In SpringBoot app when accessing h2-console get the following error.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 189.216.xxx.xxx:58157: invalid IPv6 address
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1344)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1251)
    at org.h2.util.NetworkConnectionInfo.<init>(NetworkConnectionInfo.java:37)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doGet(WebServlet.java:129)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
```

The error appears ONLY when I use h2 database "1.4.200" and SUPERIOR VERSIONS. The SpringBoot App is deployed in Azure in an App Service Linux.

The IP 189.216.xxx.xxx that appears in the error is the client IP.

[In the web browser I get error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLOJv.png)

As I said before, using h2 database version 1.4.199 and lower I do not get errors and I can access h2-console in Azure in an App Service Linux.

Strangely, deploying in localhost (http://localhost/api/v1/h2-console/) there is NO error in any version of h2.

Comment: Looks like you have added the port :58157 in a configuration file where only an IP address was expected.

Comment: Implementations of `javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` in the web server may return only IP address (there is a separate method `getRemotePort()` for port number). If `189.216.xxx.xxx:58157` was returned as IP address, something is wrong with the web server or its configuration. It isn't a bug of H2.